# Ionic2 - HTTP Error 503: POST https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova, ionic2

After putting the icon.psd and spalsh.psd files in the resources folder and writing

`ionic cordova resources` in the terminal

i got this response

`

```
HTTP Error 503: POST https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Application Error</title>
                <style media="screen">
                  html,body,iframe {
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                  }
                  html,body {
                        height: 100%;
                        overflow: hidden;
                  }
                  iframe {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        border: 0;
                  }
                </style>
          </head>
          <body>
                <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
          </body>
        </html>
```

`

Any one have Solution for this issue?

Comment: 503 is just an unavailable service. In any way it's server side.

Comment: This is embarrasing... you cannot even create a new app with Ionic, it just fails at the very earlier instances of the process... horrible product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just like you can see in **[this thread from the Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/constant-503-errors-from-resources/108312/10)** this is an error in Ionic's server-side so there's nothing you can do to fix it on your end.

I'm afraid that you can report the problem at **http://ionicframework.com/support#support** if you want, but we'd need to wait for this to be fixed by the Ionic team.

Answer (score 6):

This is an ionic server side issue ([ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/constant-503-errors-from-resources/108312/10))

You can either wait till the service is back online or you **can generate the resources locally (from ionic 5)**. You can do this simply by running the following console commands from your project folder:

Step 1: install [cordova-res tool](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-res)

```
$ npm install -g cordova-res
```

Step2: generate the resources

```
$ cordova-res
```

Comment: This solution worked for me... even using Ionic 4.7.4

Answer (score 1):

**solved**

just used by tinypng .
I got same error , but i used png images . I guess that uploading image size is very important.

icon 700kb -- 80kb

splash 5.2mb -- 700kb

And

icon  1024*1024

splash 2732*2732

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the existing platforms and run the following:

```
ionic cordova platform add <ios/android>@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is the correct size maybe you need to remove the transparent background from the image by setting it as a solid colour.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when updating to cordova 10 CLI & cordova-android@9.  Not sure why.  Ultimately if you don't need to re-generate icon/splash resources, you should be able to get past this by skipping the resources when adding the platform (`--no-resources` flag).

`ionic cordova platform add android --no-resources`

If you do need to add resources, you can do that by using @Future2020's suggestion (`npm install -g cordova-res` followed by `cordova-res`).